# formatting the date

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date formatting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009296/date-formatting-in-php)

Inside my print_r function when ran shows $message->date_sent as this 2012-03-05 00:00:00

```
echo '<td>'.date('F d, Y', $message->date_sent).'</td>';
```

Aparrently the date function is not what I'm wanting here because I just want to turn it into March 05, 2012.

Comment: You want `date('F d, Y', strtotime($message->date_sent))` since `date()` takes a UNIX timestamp and your date looks like a MySQL DATETIME

Comment: Has already been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525867/change-format-of-facebook-end-time/ And also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009296/date-formatting-in-php 
Please search before asking

Comment: While not an **identical** duplicate, the same ground is covered leading to the same result, which is use `strtotime()`

Answer (score 2):

Call [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to date's second argument

`echo '<td>'.date('F d, Y', strtotime($message->date_sent)).'</td>';`

Answer (score 0):

For Long notation of Month
January 12 2012

```
<?php echo '<td>'.date("F d Y", strtotime($message->date_sent)) .'</td>'; ?>
```

For short notation of Month
Jan 12 2012

```
<?php echo '<td>'.date("M d Y", strtotime($message->date_sent)) .'</td>'; ?>
```